# Attribute starts with selector not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of inputs as:

```
<input type="text" id="Class3Row0" name="Class3" class="Row0" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
<input type="text" id="Class3Row1" name="Class3" class="Row1" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
<input type="text" id="Class3Row2" name="Class3" class="Row0" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
.......
```

So as it can be seen, each `id` forms the pattern `"Class3RowNo"`. 
When I execute the jQuery:

```
$(function(){
        $('input[id^="Class3"]').on('mouseover',function(){
            alert("invoked!!");
        });
    });
```

The mouse when over the first `input` above(i.e. the one with `id="Class3Row0"`) the alert appears.But for other `input` elements, it does not although their `id` starts with `"Class3"`.So whats wrong here and how should I get things done?

**EDIT:**

It seems worth mentioning here that the inputs after the first `input` element are added dynamically following the simple algorithm:

1. Cloning the first input with class changed to Row1,Row2,Row3....
2. resetting their id field to their name+class

Comment: Seems to be working just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/RdYeS/

Comment: Are the other inputs added dynamically?

Comment: @Musa yes they are added on click of a button

Comment: Then you'll have to use event delegation

Comment: ^^^ see the link posted by Felix, should explain everything nicely!

Comment: Musa has the right idea, something like: http://jsfiddle.net/YBAaZ/1/

Comment: Whoops, check out http://jsfiddle.net/YBAaZ/2/ instead; it handles your request nicely.

Comment: @faino thanx! It worked like a gem. And a question to all those who have marked it as duplicate that is it not the case that "Attribute starts with selector not working in jQuery" because "Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler" so arent they different?